# Can we estimate $ \max_{x,y \in [0,1]} \,\left|\frac{\sin x - \sin y }{x-y} \right| < \infty $?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I would like to understand better the [continuity](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/continuity-dc) of [sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine).  So I am going to try to "measure" it.  I believe I can write down:

$$ \max_{x,y \in \mathbb{R}} \,\left|\frac{\sin x - \sin y }{x-y}  \right| = \; ? $$

This number should not be infinite because if $x \approx y$  then we are taking the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative):

$$ \frac{\sin x - \sin y }{x-y}  \approx \cos x \approx \cos y$$

And using the periodicity of the sine function we can restrict $x$ and $y$ to the interval $[0,2\pi]$.  This should be enough to guarantee that an upper bound exists.

$$ \max_{x,y \in [0,2\pi]} \,\left|\frac{\sin x - \sin y }{x-y}  \right| < \infty $$

Hopefully this is a well-posed problem now.  Another more refined question is to maximize this error when $x$ and $y$ are not too far apart:

$$ \max_{|x-y| < \frac{\pi}{100}} \,\left|\frac{\sin x - \sin y }{x-y}  \right| < \infty $$

---

This is known as the modulus of [continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity). In a way, we have computed a [sumset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset), $\sin (\mathbb{R}) - \sin (\mathbb{R}) \subseteq  [2,-2]$, or at least we're measuring the size of the image of $f(x,y) = \sin x - \sin y$ near the diagonal set $\{ |x-y| < \epsilon\}$.

Comment: By the mean value theorem for differentiable functions, $$\left|\frac{\sin x-\sin y}{x-y}\right|=|\cos\alpha|\le1\;,\;\;\alpha\in (x,y)\;\;or\;\;\alpha\in (y,x)$$ But perhaps you haven't yet studied differentiability...?

Comment: Your very first $\max$ is not attained anywhere, it is a $\sup$. $\sin$ is a Lipschitz-continuous function with Lipschitz constant equal to one, also because $$\frac{\sin y-\sin x}{y-x}=\frac{1}{y-x}\int_{x}^{y}\cos(t)\,dt $$

Answer (score 3):

Since $\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\,\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\,\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$, so
$$\left|\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(y)}{x-y}\right|= \left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)}{\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)}\right|\,\Biggl|\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\Biggr|\leq 1\,.$$
However, the value $1$ is not achievable (i.e., the maximum does not exist) because the inequality $\left|\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\right|<1$ holds for all $t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, but $1$ is the supremum value.

To see why $1$ is the supremum, we can set $x=3y$, so that
$$\left|\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(y)}{x-y}\right|= \left|\frac{\sin(y)}{y}\right|\,\big|\cos\left(2y\right)\big|\,.$$
Taking $y\to 0^+$, we see that $\left|\frac{\sin(y)}{y}\right|\,\big|\cos\left(2y\right)\big|\to 1^-$.

Comment: Then you can't find $(x,y)$ then maybe $1$ is too big.

Comment: The point is that $1$ is the supremum.  For any value $t<1$, there exist $x,y\in[0,1]$ such that $\left|\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(y)}{x-y}\right|>t$.

Comment: I guess $(x,y) = (0-\epsilon, 0+\epsilon)$ and the slope $m = \frac{\Delta ( \sin x)}{\Delta x}$ should be very close to (but less than) $1$.

Comment: That makes no sense.  If $x,y\in[0,1]$, then setting $x=-\epsilon$ and $y=+\epsilon$ will work only when $\epsilon=0$, but then the value $\left|\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(y)}{x-y}\right|$ is not defined for $x=y=0$.

Comment: How about $x = \epsilon$ and $y = 2\pi - \epsilon$.  Originally $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ but I argued we could have $x,y \in [0, 2\pi]$ (fixing a typo).

Comment: For $x,y\in[0,2\pi]$, then you would only show that the infimum is $0$, but there is a much better way to show that the infimum is $0$; that is, by setting $x=0$ and $y=\pi$.  In this way, you would actually show that $0$ is not just the infimum---it is the minimum.  However, for $x,y\in[0,1]$, the minimum is $\sin(1)>0$.

Answer (score 2):

use that $$\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(y)}{x-y}=\cos(\xi)$$ where $$\xi \in (x,y)$$